# str_replace_all() changes all of the string

Tags: r, string, replace, character

I am working on a character variable which I want to change the dots "." in it to underscore "*". But when I enter the code, it changes all of the character to "*______". I tried changing "A"s to "E"s which worked but I could not make it work for dots and underscore.

```r
x <- "TP.MK.CUM.YTL"
y <- str_replace_all(x, ".", "_")

y
# [1] "____________"
```

Comment: Replace `.` with `\\.`

Comment: ... because `.` is a special character in a regex.  It matches *any* character (except a line break).  You need to escape it with a backslash, so that it matches only a full stop.  But `\\` is a special character in R character strings.  So you need to escape that as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap with `fixed` as `.` is special character to match any character

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(x, fixed("."), "_")
[1] "TP_MK_CUM_YTL"
```

---

Or use `chartr` in `base R`

```
chartr(".", "_", x)
[1] "TP_MK_CUM_YTL"
```